# Borel sigma-algebra over [0,1]

Tags: measure-theory

I just started studying this, so forgive me if I get something wrong.

I have been given the following definition of a Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega=[0,1]$: It is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all intervals $(a,b)$ with $0\leq a<b\leq1$. Lets call this algebra $\mathcal{B}$.

Now apparently, every subinterval of $[0,1]$, including a half-open one like $[0,1)$, should be in $\mathcal{B}$. Even simpler, $\{0\}\in\mathcal{B}$ should be correct. Right?

I can not figure out how this would work - I know that complements, intersections and unions of any elements of $\mathcal{B}$ are again elements of $\mathcal{B}$.

With the given definition, I don't know how to obtain a subset that contains either $0$ or $1$ and not both: $0\leq a<b\leq 1, M = (a,b) => 0,1 \notin M => 0,1\in \overline{M}$.

I have searched using google and stackexchange, but I seem to have been given an uncommon definition. Is the definition wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Remember that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by *open* sets.  So the first thing you have to ask yourself is, "What do open sets look like in $[0,1]$?"  If you are familiar with topology and the notion of *subspace topology*, then in addition to all intervals of the form $(a,b)$, we also have all intervals of the form $[0,b)$, and $(a,1]$, and finally $[0,1]$ is also open in this subspace topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prove that if $A_{n} \in \mathcal{B}$ for each $n \in \Bbb N$, then $\bigcap \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_{n} \in \mathcal{B}$.

Once you have the above fact, then since $[0, \frac{1}{n}) \in \mathcal{B}$ for each $n$, we have $\bigcap \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} [0, \frac{1}{n}) = \{ 0 \} \in \mathcal{B}$.

Here is a proof for the first claim I made (try it yourself first, and when you want to see the proof, just move your mouse over the box below):

**Claim:** If $A_{n} \in \mathcal{B}$ for each $n \in \Bbb N$, then $\bigcap \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_{n} \in \mathcal{B}$.

**Proof**:

> Since $A_{n} \in \mathcal{B}$ for each $n \in \Bbb N$, and $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra (which is closed under complements), then $A_{n}^{c} \in \mathcal{B}$ for each $n$.  Then since by definition $\sigma$-algebras are closed under countable unions, we have $\bigcup \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} A^{c}_{n} \in \mathcal{B}$.  But then the complement of this set is in $\mathcal{B}$.  But $(\bigcup \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} A^{c}_{n})^{c} = \bigcap \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_{n}$, which proves $\bigcap \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_{n} \in \mathcal{B}$, as desired.

---

**UPDATE**:
As requested in the comments, if $\mathcal{B}$ represents the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing sets of the form $(a,b)$ with $a, b \in [0,1]$, then there is no way to get $\{ 0 \}$.  We can get $\{ 0, 1 \}$ by noticing this set is the complement of $(0,1)$.  But there is no way to "separate" $\{0 \}$ from the other elements as a measurable set.

Comment: What do you mean prove? The first fact comes from the definition of $\sigma$ - algebra

Comment: @Ant Sorry, I should be more clear.  By prove, what I meant was prove.  One definition of a $\sigma$-algebra is a collection of subsets that contains the entire space, and is closed under complements, and also countable unions.  If these are the only axioms you have, closure under countable intersections should be proven.

Comment: Ah I see. I've used another definition for $\sigma$-algebra then :-)

Comment: @Ant Can you share what it is?  I'm relatively new to this material, too, and this definition is the only one I've seen so far.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that this claim was true, but I hadn't looked at the proof yet. Useful! But I have an issue with the rest of your answer: You say "...since $[0,\frac{1}{n})\in B$ for each $n$, ..." which is pretty much exactly what I am doubting. $[0, ...)$ contains $0$ and not $1$, so I don't think it is in $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: @Wutz See my comment under your question.  Sets of the form $[0, a)$ **are open** in $[0,1]$ with respect to the subspace topology of $[0,1]$, which is of course what we are using.  Are you familiar with the subspace topology?  If not, then you won't understand the sets in $\mathcal{B}$ until you become familiar with it.

Comment: @user46944 That's good to know, I will familiarize myself. I already spent the last hour reading dozens of articles about this, whats a little more? But if we keep strictly to the definition of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra that was given to me, then $[0, a]$ is not in it. Would you agree?

Comment: @Wutz Actually, $[0,a]$ is in it for any $0 \leq a \leq 1$.  The argument is the same as what I did above.  First off, if $a = 1$, then $[0,1]$ is in it since $[0,1]$ is open in the subspace topology of $[0,1]$.  If $a$ is not equal to $1$, then there is some $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $a + \frac{1}{n}$ is still smaller than $1$.  Actually, for all $m \geq n$, it would be true that $a + \frac{1}{m}$ is smaller than $1$.  Then since $[0, a + \frac{1}{m})$ is open in $[0,1]$ under the subspace top. for each $m \geq n$, and we have $\bigcap \limits_{m = n}^{\infty} [0, a + \frac{1}{m}) =  [0, a]$

Comment: @Wutz ...it follows that $[0,a] \in \mathcal{B}$. (Because, as we already proved, $\sigma$-algebras are closed under countable intersections.)

Comment: @user46944 But again you just assume that $[0, a+\frac{1}{m}]\in\mathcal{B}$, even though though my definition has not mentioned subspace topology or open sets once. The way $\mathcal{B}$ is defined in my question, all we know is: $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and contains $(a,b)$ for all $0\leq a<b\leq1$. I still don't see how $[0, a+\frac{1}{m}]\in\mathcal{B}$ follows from that.

Comment: @Wutz Usually, a measure space is a triple $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$, where $X$ is your whole set, and $\Sigma$ is your $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$.  Now, when we talk about the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, this really depends on $X$.  If $X = \Bbb R$, then we would write $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)$ for the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R$.  This would be generated by sets of the form $(a,b)$ as you've said.  But our $X = [0,1]$, so we are talking about $\mathcal{B}( [0,1])$, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$ generated by the open sets.  Ok, then what are the open sets of $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Wutz Well, if a different topology isn't specified, it's automatically assumed we are talking about the subspace topology on $[0,1]$.  The subspace topology isn't at all a difficult thing to understand, and I think you should get it if you get the right instruction.  But anyway, basically the subspace topology is the topology generated by intervals $(a,b)$, as well as $[0,b)$, $(a,1]$, and $[0,1]$.  So, because of this, all open sets in $[0,1]$ are in $\mathcal{B}([0,1])$, which means sets of the form $[0, a)$ are in it.  That means in my previous argument, $[0,a + \frac{1}{m})$ is in it for

Comment: @Wutz ...each of those $m$'s I specified.  Then the countable intersection over all of those $m$'s is in it since we proved in my answer that the countable intersection of elements of $\mathcal{B}$ are in $\mathcal{B}$.  But $\bigcap \limits_{m = n}^{\infty} [0, a + \frac{1}{m}) = [0, a]$, and since the intersection is in $\mathcal{B}$, this means so is $[0,a]$.  But $a$ was arbitrarily in the interval, so any set of the form $[0,a]$ with $a \in [0,1]$ is in $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: @user46944 Maybe I'm being thick, but I feel like we are talking about different things still. Forget that $\mathcal{B}$ is supposed to be a Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. Just look at the following, because that's what my question was supposed to come down to: Let $M$ be the smallest  $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega = [1,0]$, that contains all intervals $(a,b)$ with $0\leq a<b\leq1$. Is $\{0\}\in M$? I think the answer is no. If you disagree, please don't use the assumption that $M$ is a Borel $\sigma$-algebra or how a Borel $\sigma$-algebra is usually defined in your reasoning.

Comment: @Wutz If you are defining $\mathcal{B}$ as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing sets of the form $(a,b)$, then it contains $(0,1)$, which means it contains the complement of $(0,1)$, which is $\{0, 1 \}$.  But no, I don't think there is any way to get just $\{0 \}$ after you define $\mathcal{B}$ in the way you did.

Comment: @user46944 Ok, then I wasn't completely wrong. Sorry about this, should have made the question clearer, but you understand - I don't know enough about the topic yet to do that. Anyways, if you add something along the lines of your last comment into your answer, I'll accept it, because you helped me a great deal in understanding the entire thing. And thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Wutz No problem.  As you continue working with these things, you will feel better/more confident about them (as with all math).

Answer (score 5):

You're right; the definition you quoted is wrong.  The family $\mathcal F$ of all subsets of $[0,1]$ that contain both or neither of $0$ and $1$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains the intervals $(a,b)$.  So all Borel sets according to the quoted definition are in $\mathcal F$.

Answer (score 2):

Actually your definition is wrong: the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $[0,1]$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all open sets of $[0,1]$.

Clearly, every open set $U \subset (0,1)$ is a (at most) countable union of disjoint intervals of the form $(a_i, b_i)$. This means that $U \in \mathcal{B}$ (I denote by $\mathcal{B}$ your definition of Borel $\sigma$-algebra).

However, as you pointed in your question, there are some open subsets touching the boundary of $[0,1]$. As an example, $[0,1)$ is open in $[0,1]$, hence it is a Borel subset of $[0,1]$. Actually, $[0,1) \notin \mathcal{B}$: this shows that $\mathcal{B}$ is not the Borel algebra of $[0,1]$.